# React-Router: Why does pushing to history change my url?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, history

I'm trying to utilize `createMemoryHistory` to move around without changing the url address because my app will be rendered inside an iframe. However, when I push to `history`, it seems to update my url. Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

```
//history.js
import createMemoryHistory from "history/createMemoryHistory";
const history = createMemoryHistory();
export default history;

//App.js
import history from './history/history';
...
<Router>
   <Route
      path={'/'}
      render={(props) => <Component {...props}/>}
   />
</Router>

//component.js
...
function handleClick(history) {
    history.push('somePath'); // this updates my url to be url.com/somePath
} 
return (<Button onClick={() => handleClick(this.props.history)}>);
```

Comment: can you please try `createBrowserHistory` instead of `MemoryHistory`

Comment: @RaghavGarg I just swapped to `createBrowserHistory` but it's still changing my url address :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While making use of MemoryHistory, you should pass the history object on to the Router and use it directly after importing the created history like

**App.js**

```
import history from './history/history';
...
<Router history={history}>
   <Route
      path={'/'}
      render={(props) => <Component {...props}/>}
   />
</Router>
```

**component.js**

```
import history from './history/history';
...
function handleClick() {
    history.push('somePath'); // this updates my url to be url.com/somePath
} 
return (<Button onClick={() => handleClick()}>);
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the problem, I was importing something incorrectly lol. Still stuck with `createMemoryHistory` in the end instead of `createBrowserHistory`